# htaccess redirection for subdomain

Tags: .htaccess

Can someone please help me with this htaccess, I just want this subdomain wildcard http://subdomain.example.com/login -> redirected to this link http://www.example.com/login

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example.com\login [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/login/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't too much information given but from what it sounds like you could do this fairly easily by putting in simple 301 redirect rules in the subdomain.

```
Redirect 301 /login http://www.example.com/login
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Goto your subdomain folder
2. Create .htaccess file in this folder
3. and paste this code:

`Redirect 301 /login http://www.example.com/login`